# Struggling with Differential Operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-operators

I'm taking a basic linear algebra/Differential Equations class hybrid (weird right?), and we're currently learning about differential operators. Am I correct in saying that a differential operator is a linear transformation that maps a function to it's derivative n amount of times? So the operator ${D^{(3)}}(f)$ would map from the function f to it's third derivative? Then the book introduced L, which $L(f) = {a_0}{D^{(2)}}(f) + {a_1}D(f) + {a_2}(f)$ where the a's are functions. So is L just another differential operator that can be applied to a function?

Now to the actual book question. It gives me $L_1$ which is $(xD)$, and $L_2$ which is $(xD+1)$, and it wants me to find $L_1L_2$ and $L_2L_2$. Does it just want me to multiply them?

Comment: I think those are compositions, not multiplications, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ohhhhh, my book does this stupid thing where it doesn't use parenthesis in functions. They'll just say fx instead of f(x). In this case, I think I"m supposed to find L1(L2) and L2(L1).

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. Also, does it write $D^{(3)}(f)$ or just $D^3f$? Not that it makes much of a difference.

Comment: It's written without the parenthesis, but the Latex added them. I'm pretty sure I have to rewrite D+2 as (f'+2f), then take L_1(f'+2f), resulting in x(f'+2f)', because L_1=xD. Then I would do a similar thing with the roles of L_1 and L_2 reversed to find L_2(L_1). Does that sound about right?

Comment: "But the Latex added them." [And by LaTeX you mean Frieder.](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1215170/revisions)

Comment: Oh I didn't catch that haha.

Comment: Where are you getting $D+2$ from? Don't you have $L_2=xD+1$? In other words, $L_2f=xDf+f=xf'+f$? (By the way, you sure that it's $1$ and not $I$? 'Cause I remember $I$ being defined as the identity operator, such that $If=f$ for all $f$, but you wrote $1$ here as if $L_2$ were the sum of an operator and a number rather than two operators.)

Comment: By the way, [nice music!](https://soundcloud.com/jbellstudios/battle-of-the-spheres)

Comment: EDIT: You know what, I'm sorry, it's probably a $1$. Derp.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Thank's for clearing name issues!

Comment: Yeah that should be a 1 columbus8myhw. Thanks for the music compliment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little workaround about differential operators:

$$\begin{array}{l}
{L_1} = xD\\
{L_2} = xD + 1\\
{L_2} = {L_1} + 1\\
{L_2} \circ {L_1} = ({L_1} + 1) \circ {L_1}\\
{L_2} \circ {L_1}(f) = ({L_1} + 1)({L_1}(f))\\
 = ({L_1} + 1)(x \cdot D(f))\\
 = ({L_1}(x \cdot D(f)) + x \cdot D(f)\\
 = (xD)(x \cdot D(f) + x \cdot D(f)\\
 = x \cdot D(f) + {x^2} \cdot {D^{(2)}}(f) + x \cdot D(f)\\
 = {x^2} \cdot {D^{(2)}}(f) + 2x \cdot D(f)\\
 = ({x^2} \cdot {D^{(2)}} + 2x \cdot D)(f)\\
{L_2}{L_1} = {x^2} \cdot {D^{(2)}} + 2x \cdot D\\
\\
{L_2}{L_1} = {L_1}^2 + {L_1} = xD \circ xD + xD = xD + {x^2}{D^{(2)}} + xD = {x^2}{D^{(2)}} + 2xD\\
{L_1}{L_2} = {L_1}^2 + {L_1} = xD \circ xD + xD = xD + {x^2}{D^{(2)}} + xD = {x^2}{D^{(2)}} + 2xD\\
\\
{L_2}{L_2} = ({L_1} + 1) \circ ({L_1} + 1)\\
 = {L_1}^2 + 2{L_1} + 1\\
 = xD \circ xD + 2xD + 1\\
 = xD + {x^2}{D^{(2)}} + 2xD + 1\\
 = {x^2}{D^{(2)}} + 3xD + 1
\end{array}$$